# ASM 4.1 visitLdcInsn Illegal type in constant pool

Tags: java, bytecode, cobertura, java-bytecode-asm

I am using ASM 4.1. I understand that the method visitLdcInsn requires version 49 or higher, however I am wondering how I could get visitLdcInsn to work with version 49 and lower. I know a solution is for people to compile with a higher version, but I do not believe that is a proper solution to suggest to people. Here is some test code that when I try to instrument I get the exception:

```
package mypackage;
 public class JDK4TEST {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  }
 }
```

I get the following exception:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: (class: mypackage/JDK4TEST, method: __cobertura_classmap signature: (Lnet/sourceforge/cobertura/coveragedata/LightClassmapListener;)V) Illegal type in constant pool

If more code is required, this is part of the cobertura 2.0 code on github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `visitLdcInsn` method were there from the beginning, but some of the accepted parameter types depend on the class format version, e.g. `Type` and `Handle` values are acceptable for class format 51.0 and higher. See [corresponding JavaDoc](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html#visitLdcInsn%28java.lang.Object%29).

Also note, that ASM's `ClassWriter` doesn't check validity of produced bytecode. You need to add [CheckClassAdapter](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/util/CheckClassAdapter.html) into the visitor's chain before `ClassWriter`.

Comment: Thank you! The CheckClassAdapter class helped me debug further as to the exact line that the exception was coming from. The root cause of my issue was I was passing a Class Type to visitLdcInsn which is not compatible with previous versions.